# Wi-Fi Drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, wifi-hardware-switch

Whenever I try and update my Wi-Fi driver I get the following error:

‘’’pk-client-error-quark: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
bemwl-kernel-source: Depends: dkms but it is not installable
Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed’’’

Any ideas? I’ve tried a bunch of different things and can’t get anything to work.

Comment: did you try installing libc6-dev then your wifi driver ?

Comment: We need more information in order to understand the issue. We need to know what driver you're trying to install and where you obtained it. We also need to know *exactly* what actions you've taken so far. You need to describe exactly what you do to get this error. We also need the full, unaltered text of any errors along with the steps needed to produce them. Please use [code block formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) and do not manipulate anything inside the paste from your terminal. Tag me @nmath when you are finished editing your question with all requested information.

Comment: Statements like "tried a bunch of things" and "doesn't work" unfortunately aren't very useful in problem solving. Details should be specific and reproducible. It's possible that one or more of your actions was destructive and needs to be reversed, so it's essential to know exactly what you tried.

Comment: Please reboot and do: `sudo apt update` and next: `sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential` Next, edit your question to include the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Since no one has asked I will. Why are you trying to update the driver? Was something not working? Was there an error or errors about the existing driver?